# ring monoid, can anyone give example of one that is not the other

Tags: ring

Everything i have read says a monoid is a group without inverse and also the same thing about a ring such as the ring of polynomials. Can anyone give examples of something that belongs to one of these but is not the other.
Or is it that a monoid must include an identity but is not necessarily a requirement to be a ring. If so is this the only difference?

Comment: Can you please be more specific to the problem you are facing? I don't think stack overflow is exact place for code examples. Usually people share the code they are using and others correct using their code snippets.

Comment: this is not an example of code. Don't know how to be more specific. If there is no difference between a monoid and a ring then why are there two separate definitions. Other than that there is no problem i am facing. Don't really know how to be more simple than that question. Can anyone give any example of a monoid which is not a ring? Can anyone give an example of a ring which is not a monoid ?